# Escape backslash in JSON encoding python

Tags: python, escaping, json

I m trying to JSON encode the following dict. But in this case, the `message` which is actually a [unicode character DEVANAGARI LETTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92e/index.htm).

So, while encoding this `dict` into a json object, it seems to escaping the backslash("\") with two backslashes("\") in `message`.

How do I change this to just one backslash "\" after encoding it with `json.dumps()`

I m using the following `custom encoder`, to `encode` the dict to json.

```
class MyCustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        # the json obj
        count = 0
        for ob in obj:
            obj[count]['message'] = unicode(obj[count]['message']).replace("\\u","\u")
            count += 1
        return super(MyCustomJsonEncoder, self).encode(obj)

[{
    'virality': '4.6%',
    'post_engaged': 150,
    'description': '',
    'post_impressions': 1631,
    'post_story': 75,
    'name': '',
    'source': '',
    'comment_count': 16,
    'link': '',
    'text': '',
    'created_time': '03:10 AM,<br>May 13, 2013',
    'message': '\u092e\u0941\u0930\u0932\u0940 \u0938\u093e\u0930:-     \u0939\u0947 \u092e\u0940\u0920\u0947',
    'id': u'182929845081087_572281819479219',
    'status_type': 'status',
    'likes_count': 55
}]
```

Comment: Passing the `ensure_ascii` option as False to `dumps` will make it work the way you want although I am not sure whether it will cause other parts of your code to break. But it may be worth trying to see if it really solves your problem. See the [docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)

Comment: Nope ensure_ascii had no effect.

Comment: try specifying the `message` value as unicode

Comment: if all you want to do is pre-process the data to convert the values to unicode, try something like this `json.dumps([dict((k, unicode(v)) for k, v in x.iteritems()) for x in data], ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: But, pre-processing that still doesnt seem to be escaping the backslashes"\\".

Answer (score 1):

Use a `unicode` literal so that the `\u` escape sequence is understood instead of having the compiler think you mean `\\u`.

```
u'\u092e....
```

Comment: I mean, I ve included the custom encoder that does try to convert it unicode, but it still doesnt seem to unescape it.

Comment: The problem with the source is that there is a space between `u` and the string for the `id` key